# javascript function only looking at first element

Tags: javascript, jquery, haml

```
:JavaScript

function showstuff(content#{g.id}){
   document.getElementById(content#{g.id}).style.display="block";
   document.getElementById(more#{g.id}).style.display="none";
}
function hidestuff(content#{g.id}){
   document.getElementById(content#{g.id}).style.display="none";
   document.getElementById(more#{g.id}).style.display="inline";
}
```

This is my JavaScript code, it works for the first element `content` but doesn't show/hide the second one `more`.

This is the rendered code:

```
<script>
            function showstuff(content1){
             document.getElementById(content1).style.display="block";
             document.getElementById(more1).style.display="none";
            }
            function hidestuff(content1){
             document.getElementById(content1).style.display="none";
             document.getElementById(more1).style.display="inline";
            }
</script>

<div id="1">
  <h3>title</h3>
  <p>
    text
  </p>
  <a style="display:inline;" onclick="showstuff('content1')" id="more1">Read More</a>
  <div style="display: none;" id="content1">
    <p> content </p>
    <a onclick="hidestuff('content1')">Show Less</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: And what templating system is that, what do the selectors represent, are those ID's, and are you using the same ID multiple times etc? This is totally unreadable to me!

Comment: Damn, please provide rendered HTML markup, not this unreadable code done for teletoobies

Comment: I've not used `haml` but it looks like those elements use class, not id?

Comment: @Anton looks like you are right! But "it works for the first element"

Comment: `more1` is undefined here. It could be: `document.getElementById('more1')` but surely not what you exactly expect

Comment: Pass more1 to the function `hidestuff('content1','more1');` and `function hidestuff(content1,more1)`

Comment: Using anton's comment code, you should be able to fix your issue

Comment: I still don't get it at all? Why would you use some strange templating tags as argument names for a function that you're passing strings to? It makes absolutely no sense at all.

Answer (score 1):

Let's say that `#{g.id}` has a value of `1`. As a result, you get generated JavaScript code that looks like this:

```
function showstuff(content1){
    document.getElementById(content1).style.display="block";
    document.getElementById(more1).style.display="none";
}
function hidestuff(content1){
    document.getElementById(content1).style.display="none";
    document.getElementById(more1).style.display="inline";
}
```

So when you call `showstuff('something')` inside of the function body there's a variable called `content1` with a value of `'something'`. That gets passed to the first line of code fine, and it correctly selects an element. Do you have a `more1` variable defined elsewhere, though? I doubt it, so there's no element to select, and therefore nothing to change the `style.display` property of.

Perhaps you meant to do something more like this:

```
function showstuff(id) {
    document.getElementById('content' + id).style.display="block";
    document.getElementById('more' + id).style.display="none";
}
```

Then you'd call it like so:

```
showstuff(#{g.id});
```

and it would show/hide the elements with IDs `content1` and `more1`.

Comment: I've updated my question with the haml code i'm using

Comment: @CarlaDessi Well, your HTML generating code just makes me more convinced that what I've posted is correct. Try changing the function to what I've suggested, then modifying this: `:onclick => "showstuff('content#{g.id}')"` to `:onclick => "showstuff(#{g.id})"`

Comment: @CarlaDessi Essentially you want to pass the dynamic value from your (I assume server-side) code when **calling** the function, not when declaring it.